# What should I do with schematics for the opposite faction?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just had a lockbox come back with a schematic inside that is for a Jedi Consular (or other Republic side class).

Being Sith, I have no use for this and presume selling it to be pointless, again, presuming as I can only sell to Sith on the GTN.

1. Is the assumption that I can only sell to the Sith side correct?
2. Is dumping the schematic the only real option?

Found [a post](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=138897) that indicates it may be possible to sell these, but, cannot confirm at the moment:

> Investigation and Underworld Trading can yield schematics for the opposite faction, making them useless to the player that received them and generally unsellable because no one wants them (although they can be sold in Nar Shaddaa to the opposite faction, but in general you can't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has all changed!

All GTN kiosks are now cross-faction.  So you can both sell the schematic to the other side as well as use the schematic and sell the crafted items to the other side.  Finally, you can send mail to your alts of the other faction.

Comment: Only if they're part of your legacy, but legacies have been made fairly easy to get as well...

Comment: @Shadur Hmm, do you need to set up legacy relationships between your characters to make them part of the legacy or is it automatic once you've unlocked your legacy?

Comment: Need to set them up manually.

Comment: To update on this, no you don't need to set up legacy relationships in order to mail to your alts.  5 of mine are not in my family tree thing and I can mail to them just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently the GTN on Nar Shaddaa and Tatooine is cross-faction.

Of course, if you do so you're also knowingly offering things for sale that can only be used by your enemies, so...

Comment: Will do some testing of this and accept if true.

Comment: Can confirm, I'm republic and after looting a few dark side only items that wouldn't sell on the Republic Fleet GTN, they sold almost straight away in Nar Shadaa. Of course if you keep the schematic and craft the items to sell on Nar Shadaa you can do a decent bit of profiteering!

Comment: ... hey, there's a thought. Contribute to the war effort by gouging the other side economically!

Comment: @GAThrawn Can you confirm that was Dark side items or actual Imperial class items? There is a difference obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can hope that the legacy system lets you transfer items to your 'other side' alts (no word on that but legacy is supposed to encourage you to have alts).

You can also sell it in the Nar Shaddaa GTN. There are actually 3 independent GTNs: Empire, Republic and Hutt. Both factions have access to the Hutt GTN. Unfortunately, not many people use it since you have to fly to Nar Shaddaa (and go through the necessary 8 screen loads) only to check items there.  Hopefully they'll add a terminal in the fleet some day.

Comment: I was told you can mail items to your alts, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/43518/6066

Comment: you definitely can mail items to your alts, but I think that doesn't include (right now) alts of the other faction. I could be wrong though

Comment: Somehow I can't see the republic setting up a trading hub to sell weapons and enhancements to their mortal enemies in their central fleet headquarters...